# ES import passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

Can anyone help me use ES import version of the: require('./config/passport')(passport);. I cant get this to work. I don't think you can use both ES import and require at the same time. I get and error that require is undefined.

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const URL = createRequire(import.meta.url);
import passport from 'passport'


import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js'
import userRoutes from './routes/user.js'
import loginRoutes from './routes/login.js'

const app = express();
dotenv.config();
require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, we can not use require which is commonjs modules with import which is ES6 modules.
Though the solution is really simple. Basically, you have to pass `passport` as an argument to the function exported from `./config/passport`.
All you have to do is just import the function as is and pass passport as an argument.

So here's what you need to do:-

---

config/passport.js

```
export default = (passport) => {
 /* use passport here */
}
```

---

index.js

```
import passport from "passport";
import passportConfig from "./config/passport";

passportConfig(passport);
```

Answer (score 1):

Aryaman is correct but I would like to offer a slightly different solution.

I would recommend that you keep passports logic out of the main `app.js/ index.js` file as much as possible. I create a `config` folder with the main `passport.js` and then a `strategies` folder that has logic for how users will login.

[image]

in your main entry point file eg `app.js`

pull in passport's config passing app.

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
require('./src/config/passport')(app);
```

Your config file eg:`passport.js` should look like this

```
import passport from 'passport';

require('./strategies/local.strategy')(); //Or whatever strategy you are using

const passportConfig = (app) => {
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  // stores user to session
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });

  // retrieves user from session
  passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });
};

export default passportConfig;
```

Example local strategy aka custom strategy

```
import passport from 'passport';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import axios from 'axios';

const localStrategy = () => {
  passport.use(new Strategy(
    {
      usernameField: 'userName',
      passwordField: 'password',
    },
    (username, password, done) => {
        const loginUrl = `${process.env.base_url}/api/core/security/login`;
        const body = {
          InstanceName: process.env.instance_name,
          Username: username,
          UserDomain: process.env.user_domain,
          Password: password,
        };
        axios.post(loginUrl, body)
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.IsSuccessful === true) {
              const user = {
                token: response.data.RequestedObject.SessionToken,
                userId: response.data.UserId,
                userName: username,
              };
              done(null, user);
            } else {
              // handle failed login
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => 
            //Handle the error
        }
      ))
    }

    export default localStrategy;
```

Comment: the problem is we can't use require with type module in node. so this your line `require('./src/config/passport')(app)` will throw an error. @Aryaman Grover answer works